# Gradient Border on Outer Edges of DataGridHeader

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid, styles

See the image below...

[image]

This is a screen shot taken from an application that was created in c++ using QT. I need to create a similar look by adding gradient borders to the outside vertical edges of my DataGrid header and I do not see a property of the DataGrid that will allow me to accomplish this. Using the DataGridColumnHeader style below, I have acheived the look I am after minus the border on the outside edges. How can I add these borders to the outside of the header only?

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                <Border BorderBrush="{StaticResource ContentPanelHeaderBackgroundBrush}" 
                        BorderThickness="0,1,0,0"
                        CornerRadius="2,2,0,0">
                    <DockPanel Background="{StaticResource ContentPanelHeaderBackgroundBrush}" Width="auto">
                        <Border BorderThickness="0,1,0,0" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" BorderBrush ="{StaticResource ContentPanelBottomBorderBrush}" />
                            <Grid Height="22">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                     <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                     <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="center" Margin="4" />
                            </Grid>
                    </DockPanel>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4,0,4,0" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource FontActiveBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource MainFont}" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="11" />
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left" />
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="22" />
    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a Tool like Snoop to inspect the XAML-Tree at runtime. It seems to me that there is an additional item rendered somewhere in the tree having its default template applied. Since you don't seem to overwrite all default templates in the tree I guess you'll find the right element this way (just gotta look for an item with background or border being black).

You can find the tool here: http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thanks for the response. The tool looks quite useful. I have updated my question to clarify what I need as the image is a screenshot of an existing application that I need to emulate in WPF.